# UILabel Font Size Does Not Change in XIB while Color Does

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts, uilabel, xib

This question seems simple, but this problem turned me crazy after days since none of the answers could solve my problem so far. I will be glad if someone can help me to figure it out.

So, I have a .xib file where I created a subview (called StaticDetailVerticalView) and I have also another .xib file for the whole page's view (called TripDetailView), and lastly, this TripDetailView is being used inside of a controller (called TripDetailViewController). My font problem occurs in StaticDetailVerticalView.

First, I was trying to set the fonts with an outlet from .xib with the methods `[self.label setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20.0]` and `self.label.font = [self.label.font fontWithSize:20.0]`. Then secondly, I tried setting from the TripDetailView by creating a IBInspectable fontSize inside StaticDetailVerticalView with direct setting from TripDetailView.xib file.

Also, when I try to change the color or the text by calling the methods exact same places with font changes, everything changes accordingly but the font size.

I hope there will be an answer to be accepted :) Joking aside, I really stuck in here.

Please ask me for further details, or any files that I can share for you if you need one. I am not adding the codes or screenshots since I believe this is not a problem by code based but something that I am missing about the outlets.

You can find the all three .xib files mentioned above [here](https://ufile.io/ga5oi).

Thanks for all the helps and answers!

Comment: Is your label's "Autoshrink" property set to `Fixed Font Size`?

Comment: Yes it is, I also tried giving minimum value as the desired and setting to that value at the same time @DonMag

Comment: hmm... sounds really odd... If you want to put up your .xib files somewhere, I'll be glad to take a look.

Comment: I know.. Of course I can, does ss work for you? Without the source code, only .xib files would not mean anything I guess, but if you want .xib files I can provide

Comment: The .xib files alone would at least allow inspection of objects... If you can include minimal code to demonstrate the issue, of course that would be better.

Comment: I will try my best on it, later if you need more I can also give you more as needed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155021/discussion-between-kutay-demireren-and-donmag).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to adjust the font size in your StaticDetailVerticalView.xib

1. Go to StaticDetailVerticalView.xib
2. Clic on the label you want to change the font's size
3. Clic on the button "Show the attributes inspector"
4. Then, you can change the font manually.

Comment: Is the size of your Label big enough to store the new size you want to set ? (Should not be the reason of your problem but we never know).
Also did you try this method : `yourLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20]` ? EDIT: Sorry I missed in your question that you already tried it...

Comment: No I had not but that does not affect as well. But I tried making the UILabel so big so that every font can fit into, did not work out as well

Comment: Any luck fixing this issue?